# Neo4J CSV LOAD relationships

Tags: neo4j

All

I'm a very ne beginner with Neo4j.

Now I've data import problem.

I use java and python to import data from oracle to neo4j and found both are too slow(I have about 100 million rows of the table)
So I consider Cypher Sentence: LOAD CSV

I export the csv file of Movie Graph of the community, as the image shown.

Now how can I use the LOAD CSV (export.csv) to build a graph data to restore the Movie Graph?
I found little info on the Neo4J manual about import data.

Thanks!![enter image description here][1]

Yours, Jesse

Comment: Please read: neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/ and neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/

Comment: Your image is missing!

Comment: and share your load csv statement and the output of `:schema`

Answer (score 1):

[There's actually pretty good documentation on how to use LOAD CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html).

It's full of useful examples.

They even have an example that's directly tied to the movies CSV:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.7/csv/import/movies.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (country:Country { name: csvLine.country })
CREATE (movie:Movie { id: toInt(csvLine.id), title: csvLine.title, year:toInt(csvLine.year)})
CREATE (movie)-[:MADE_IN]->(country)
```

Vaya con dios, mi amigo.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can use csv to create both nodes and relationships. However, the insert efficiency is too low:it takes 30s to create 1,000 nodes and 7,000 relationships, and 50mins to create 100,000 nodes and 700,000 relationships. Now I have 7,50,000 nodes and 100,000,000 relationships to create. How can I this? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Read the links I provided above, most likely you forgot to create indexes / constraints.